# How can I use form_for to display a text_field that cannot be edited?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set up a form on one of my pages that lists some info that should not be editable. My code for the page looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @quote do |f| %>
    <h2 class='h2Title'>Follow Up Popup</h2>
    <div class="field" id="msQuoteNumber">
        <%= f.label "Quote Number:" %>
        <%= f.text_field :quote_number %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

My page looks like this:

[image]

Right now I'm using `f.text_field :quote_number` to fill in the field with the `quote_number` from my database. This however lets the user type whatever they want into that field which I don't want. Is there a different method I can use besides `text_field` that just simply shows the `quote_number` as regular text?

Comment: You might just populate an ordinary "<p>... your Number  ... </p>"  or user the readonly attribute look; https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: When I try this: `<div>Quote Number: <input type="text" name="msQuoteNumber" value=:quote_number readonly=><br></div>` it shows the actual words `:quote_number` in the form. How do I get it to show the value of `:quote_number`?

Comment: I do not know ruby but try: "value=:quote_number" "readonly=readonly"

or 

"value="<%= f.text_field :quote_number %> "readonly=readonly"

play with the quotes until sinthax is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just display the input field and disable only in case of editing:
`<%= f.text_field :quote_number, disabled: !(@quote.new_record?) %>`

In Controller, just remove the key `:quote_number` from permitted attributes in case if you are editing so that no one can update the quote number after changing it via Inspect Element functionality of the browser and then submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Use a label like the line above

Was:

```
<%= f.label "Quote Number:" %>
<%= f.text_field :quote_number %>
```

Change to:

```
 <%= f.label "Quote Number:" %>
 <%= f.label :quote_number %>
```

Comment: I had tried this and it only displays the words `Quote number` where it should display the actual value of the quote.

Comment: Your controller needs to update a label value, not the text_field text.